# Is it possible to compile so that erroneous std::vector access calls will exit the program, and with a helpful error message?

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, compilation

Consider this code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
main()
{
    std::vector <int> x(1);
    for(int q=0;; q++)
    {
        int y = x[q];
        std::cout << q << " ";
    }
}
```

On my system with g++, this prints up to 32570 before crashing with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Presumably, It takes that long because ~32570 is the size of the smallest chunk of memory that the OS and/or allocator will allocate to the vector. But of course, any time we do an operation like this past the end of the array is normally a bug. So it would be nice if I could have the program exit with a helpful error message whenever this occurs.

A few years ago with Xcode I recall that behavior occurring where it would exit with the type (and name?) of the `std::vector`. Currently I'm on Linux with g++. Is there any solution along these lines (or something else)?

Comment: Related: [How to make std::vector's operator compile doing bounds checking in DEBUG but not in RELEASE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1290396/96780)

Comment: I know this still requires changes in code, but iterating over containers and certainly the range-based-for eliminate most of these issues without having to investigate why the program stopped.  I admit the exiting with a message is better than undefined behavior like overwriting memory.

Comment: Related: [No compilation error or run time error when index out of range of vector class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27754726/96780).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to [enable debug mode in STL containers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode).

Alternatively you can also use specific debug containers which live in the [`__gnu_debug` namespace](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode), e.g. `__gnu_debug::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <debug/vector>

int main()
{
    __gnu_debug::vector <int> x(1);
    for(int q = 0; ; q++)
    {
        int y = x[q];
        std::cout << q << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the advantage of debug containers is you can isolate specific containers and then easily switch them over std:: containers later on? Is there anyway I can change this output or interpret it somehow? `Objects involved in the operation: sequence "this" @ 0x0x7ffc2b96e950 {type = NSt7__debug6vectorIiSaIiEEE;}`

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're stuck with the standard debug error messages, unless you want to start hacking the libstdc++ source arouund. Having said that though, see [_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_VERIFY](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_design.html).

Comment: do you know if -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG is generally compatible with boost?

Comment: boost references `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` in a couple of headers (`asio/buffer.hpp` and `detail/container_fwd.hpp`), but I think it uses its own debug mechanism internally.

Comment: I couldn't get -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG to work with my project. I think it was conflicting with boost or cpp-netlib. Replacing most of my std::vector with __gnu_debug::vector did the trick though, and wasn't too difficult.

Comment: For future reference you could perhaps `#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG` locally inside your source files, after any boost includes but before any STL includes. Alternatively just use `using __gnu_debug::vector;`, which I guess is what you did.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) member function which throws an `out_of_range` exception if your index violates the vector's range.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::vector <int> x(1);
  for(int q=0;; ++q) {
    int y = x.at(q);
    std::cout << q << " ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Good to know. Although this would require me to replace all the element access calls in my program. I would still like to have a compiler option if possible.